# no such file to load -- bundler/setup when capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, capistrano, bundle

What the problem is? Bundler installed on the remote machine. Here is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Bundler is installed at the system level and not the user level.  You can also install Bundler using the Capistrano shell, assuming Capistrano deploys as a user with a password and sudo access on your box.

Example:

```
$ cap shell         # from within your project

cap> sudo apt-get install rubygems      # or however you prefer to 
                                        # install rubygems on your box

...
...  # output
...

cap> sudo gem install bundler
```